# Solutions of equation $y^5+1=x^2 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Working in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. I am trying to prove that there is no solution $$x\equiv3\mod4$$ for $|x|\geq 2$. I already know $5|x$ and $x$ is odd.

Comment: For $x, y \in\mathbb{Z^+}$ this may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture

Comment: I still can't proof it..

Comment: Have you tried looking at $y^5+1$ mod 4 and mod 5? (you might want to use fermat's little theorem)

Comment: @Atr Technically Catalan proves it almost immediately, but that just seems like overkill for me.

Comment: @MXYMXY Its also only a conjecture

Comment: @N.S.John It's proven. See the wiki page.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  $$(x+1)(x-1)=y^5$$

Now $(x+1,x-1)|2$

Case $\#1:(x+1,x-1)=1$ if $x\pm1$ are odd $\iff x$ is even,

Case $\#2:$
If $x\pm1$ are even, divide both by $2$ so that $\left(\dfrac{x+1}2,\dfrac{x-1}2\right)=1$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: This seems somewhat difficult even afterwards.. Don't we have to find integer solutions to things like $a^5-8b^5=2$ or something? Is that easy?

Comment: @N.S.John I know that, the proof and all. I'm asking if it is easy. I think that some extra context needs to be added to this answer.

Comment: @MXYMXY It is very easy - if $2\mid a^5$, then $4\mid a^5$.

Comment: @Wojowu I know this, but I just felt that it wasn't very immediate for me. Maybe I'm just stupid, but it was just a recommendation.

Comment: So this reduces the case in which the OP was interested to the equation $a^5-8b^5=1$. This is, to be frank, no simpler than the original equation. Probably Chein's (elementary) proof is the easiest one, but it is not trivial.